# p:commandLink doesn't call actionlistener in p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

This is the XHTML code

```
<p:commandLink style="width: 10px;height: 10px;" 
               actionListener="#{InboxBean.archiveInboxRecord(actionEvent)}">
   <img src="../resources/images/arch.png" />
   <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{inboxitem}" 
                                target="#{InboxBean.selectedInbox}"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

and this is bean

```
public  void archiveInboxRecord(ActionEvent actionEvent){
   System.err.println("Record Title is " + this.selectedInbox.AppTitle);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after friends aid ..

the right code is

```
<p:commandLink  style="width: 10px;height: 10px;" 
                                                   process="inboxdt"  
                                                   actionListener ="#{InboxBean.archiveInboxRecord(actionEvent)}" >

                                      <img src="../resources/images/arch.png" />
                                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{inboxitem}" target="#{InboxBean.selectedInbox}" />
                                    </p:commandLink>
```

and the key solution is process the datatable Id "inboxdt"

Answer (score 1):

An argument actionEvent do not require to send when you use actionListener. You should use the below code instead.

```
<p:commandLink style="width: 10px;height: 10px;" 
               actionListener="#{InboxBean.archiveInboxRecord}" >
   <img src="../resources/images/arch.png" />
   <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{inboxitem}" 
                                target="#{InboxBean.selectedInbox}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your datatable is in a form tag
like that :

```
<h:form id="form">
<p:datatable var="student" value="#{studentbean.listStd}">
<p:column headerText="column 1">Something here ..</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Action">
<p:commandLink style="width: 10px;height: 10px;" 
               actionListener="#{InboxBean.archiveInboxRecord}" >
   <img src="../resources/images/arch.png" />
   <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{inboxitem}" 
                                target="#{InboxBean.selectedInbox}" />
</p:commandLink>
</p:column>
</p:datatable>
</h:form>
```

Or try to put your commandLink in a from tag like that:

```
<h:form id="formLink">
<p:commandLink style="width: 10px;height: 10px;" 
               actionListener="#{InboxBean.archiveInboxRecord}" >
   <img src="../resources/images/arch.png" />
   <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{inboxitem}" 
                                target="#{InboxBean.selectedInbox}" />
</p:commandLink>
</h:form>
```